# Using mockito to initialize spring batch jobExecution

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

PROBLEM:

I am writing unit test for one of my spring batch job methods. I use mockito to mock my batch job dependencies. Everything is fine until jobExecution comes to play. The method I wanna test makes a call to jobExecution variable, but then it gives me NPE (NullPointerException) and I do not succeed to mock this with mockito.

---

THINGS I HAVE TRIED:

Like mentioned in problem section, I tried to mock it with @Mock annotation.

---

CODE:

My method that needs to be unit tested (currentJobExecution is the line that gives me error):

```java
    @Override
    public List<Date> getValidDates() {
        List<Date> allDates = dateService.findAllFailedDates(getJobName(), false);
        List<Date> datesThatCanBeWorkedOn = getAllDatesThatHaveNecessaryDependencies(allDates);
        Collection<Date> datesThatCannotBeWorkedOn = CollectionUtils.subtract(allDates, datesThatCanBeWorkedOn);
        currentJobExecution.getExecutionContext().put("datesThatCannotBeWorkedOn", datesThatCannotBeWorkedOn);
        return datesThatCanBeWorkedOn;
    }
```

My unit test that tries to test the code above:

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class ValidDateReaderTest extends BaseTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private ValidDateReader validDateReader;

    @Mock
    private DateService dateService;

    @Mock
    private JobExecution currentJobExecution;

    @Mock
    private JobInstance jobInstance;

    @Test
    public void getDatesNeededProcessingTest() {

        when(jobInstance.getJobName()).thenReturn(BatchNames.VALID_DATE_READER);
        when(currentJobExecution.getJobInstance()).thenReturn(jobInstance);
        List<Date> allDates = new ArrayList<>();
        allDates.add(DateUtils.addDays(new Date(), -5));
        allDates.add(DateUtils.addDays(new Date(), -4));
        allDates.add(DateUtils.addDays(new Date(), -3));
        allDates.add(DateUtils.addDays(new Date(), -2));
        allDates.add(DateUtils.addDays(new Date(), -1));
        when(dateService.findAllFailedDates(BatchNames.VALID_DATE_READER, false))
                .thenReturn(allDates);
        assertEquals(1, validDateReader.getValidDates().size());
    }

}
```

---

EXPECTED RESULTS AND ACTUAL:

When I remove this currentJobExecution

```java
currentJobExecution.getExecutionContext().put("datesThatCannotBeWorkedOn", datesThatCannotBeWorkedOn);
```

from the method which I want to test, then test is completed successfully. But I cannot remove it, since it is a part of business logic.

Comment: Ofcourse it fails with a `NullPointerException`. There is no behavior registered for `currentJobExecution.getExecutionContext()` and hence Mockito does the default which is to return `null`. You will need another `when` clause in your setup.

Comment: I did as @Spac Valentin suggested. Seems like a same thing as you said. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `currentJobExecution.getExecutionContext()` is returning `null`. You may want to mock it too:

```
when(currentJobExecution.getExecutionContext()).thenReturn(new ExecutionContext());
```

Comment: Thank you. This solved my problem. I accepted this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Either call this before your test logic (e.g. in an `@Before` method):

```
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
```

Or change your unit test runner to `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` if you don't need a Spring context.

Comment: I did as @Spac Valentin suggested. But still thank you for your effort and suggestion.